# How can I get more internal space for apps?

Tags: root-access, insufficient-memory, partitions

I have read several places on this but the answers all seem to be the same. The problem is that I keep running out of space on my /data partition. The steps I've taken to fix this problem: move all apps that will function on sdcard to sdcard, also clear data on apps but the problem with this is that as soon as you open them again they act like a fresh install and then refill data.

My device stats 1gb /data partition 30gb 'internal' sdcard partition, Android 4.2.2 with root kernel 3.0.36+. Ideas I've had to fix this problem and the problems I faced attempting to use them:

1. Repartition some of the /sdcard space to /data, problem is I can't really find any specific instructions on how to do this and from what I have read I'm not really sure if I can because my "userdata" (/data) partition is at mtd6 and my "user" (/sdcard) partition is at mtd9 with "kpanic" and "system" at mtd 7 & 8 respectively, the guides mention mmc blocks instead of mtd which one seems to be an emulation of the other. I have seen other devices of the same model come from the factory with 2gb of /data storage.
2. Move the /data/data contents of an app to sdcard and bind mount that location, problem is these directories always contain a /lib link thats points to wherever the apps installed package location is and this link can't seem to be made, also not sure if I can make permissions right. As I understand it, when android installs an app to the sdcard it creates a small ext4 partition to contain the app package so I'm wondering if its possible to do something similar and then bind an apps /data/data assets to it.

Comment: Usually the answer would be to use adopted storage (use sd-card as internal) but your device is so old that this feature is not available. Are you sure the device is worth the effort?

Comment: Create a second partition on SD card with `ext4` filesystem and mount it at `/data/data` or `/data/media` on every boot.

Comment: @Irfan Latif That is exactly what I thinking when I wrote the last sentence under 2. But as I explained in 1 I have not been able to figure out how repartition the /sdcard and all the guides I've run accross refer to mmc not mtd. If you could explain to me how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

On a device with such limited resources, your best bet by far is to eliminate as many apps as possible.

Any useless bloatware that was preinstalled might be able to be disabled.  This will prevent them from growing.

Any apps that connect you to sites that are accessible with a browser- use the browser and ditch the apps.

A great, small, very fast browser for such a mission is Lightning.

Lightning (Lightweight web browser) - https://f-droid.org/app/acr.browser.lightning